# Read in table from text file with variable number of whitespaces as separator

Tags: r

I would like to read a .txt file with the following structure:

```
ID      Chr   Allele:Effect ...
Q1        1     1:-0.133302   2: 0.007090
Q2        1     1:-0.050089   2: 0.021212
Q3        1     1: 0.045517   2:-0.038001
```

The problem is that

1. the field separator is a variable number of whitespaces, and
2. I need to get rid of the leading numbers in the second and third column.

Finally, the result should look like:

```
qtl_id    chr   eff_1         eff_2
Q1        1     -0.133302     0.007090
Q2        1     -0.050089     0.021212
Q3        1      0.045517     -0.038001
```

edit

`head(read.table(file = fpath, sep = "", header = TRUE))` yields

```
ID         Chr Allele.Effect         ...
Q1  1 1:-0.133302            2:    0.007090
Q2  1 1:-0.050089            2:    0.021212
Q3  1          1:      0.045517 2:-0.038001
Q4  1          1:      0.018582 2:-0.041846
Q5  1 1:-0.146560            2:    0.005473
Q6  1 1:-0.048240            2:    0.069418
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I applied a brute force method. First the lines are read by 'readLines' without separation. 'gsub' removes the 'number:'-pieces, and 'strsplit' splits each line. The intermediate result is the list 'A'. 'A[[1]]' is the vector of column names,
'A[[2]]' represents the first row of the data frame, and so on. Then we can piece together the data frame 'df' from the components of 'A'.

```
A <- lapply( readLines(filename),
             function(x)
             {
               strsplit( gsub( pattern="[0-9]+[ ]*[:][ ]*",
                               replacement="",
                               x=as.character(x)                        ),
                         "[ ]+")
             } )

df <- data.frame()
for (n in 2:length(A)) { df <- rbind(df,t(unlist(A[[n]]))) }
colnames(df) = unlist(A[[1]])
```

Unfortunately all entries of 'df' are still factors:

```
> df
  ID Chr Allele:Effect       ...
1 Q1   1     -0.133302  0.007090
2 Q2   1     -0.050089  0.021212
3 Q3   1      0.045517 -0.038001
> df$"Allele:Effect"
[1] -0.133302 -0.050089 0.045517 
Levels: -0.133302 -0.050089 0.045517
```

We can change this as follows:

```
for (m in 1:ncol(df))
{
  n <- as.numeric(df[,m])
  v <- suppressWarnings( as.numeric(levels(df[,m])[n]) )

  if (!any(is.na(v))) { df[,m] <- v }
}
```

Now the numbers are numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Use read.table with sep="". It is designed to handle this case. In the following example I saved your file to "qt.csv" and read it in that way. Worked fine.

```
> read.table("qt.csv",sep="",header=T)
1 qtl_id chr     eff_1     eff_2
2     Q1   1 -0.133302  0.007090
3     Q2   1 -0.050089  0.021212
4     Q3   1  0.045517 -0.038001
```

**Update:**

To answer the new request (as I understand it), I read in the other file now, and deleted those pesky characters.

```
f <- readLines("allele2.csv")
f <- gsub("(\\d)\\: ","\\1",f)   # get rid of the spaces after the colon

df <- read.table(textConnection(f),sep="",header=T)

df[[2]] <- as.numeric(gsub("^\\d\\:","",df[[2]]))
df[[3]] <- as.numeric(gsub("^\\d\\:","",df[[3]]))
df[[4]] <- as.numeric(gsub("^\\d\\:","",df[[4]]))
df
```

yielding

```
  ID Chr Allele.Effect       ...
1 Q1   1     -0.133302 20.007090
2 Q2   1     -0.050089 20.021212
3 Q3   1     10.045517 -0.038001
```

Comment: This is more like a comment, please expand your answer to cover point 2 as well.

Comment: Looks like the OP used a similar command and updated the post

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the data has the regular structure you have provided, then reading it as fixed columns should work.  Here I suggest you prepare the file first by saving the file without the header, and replacing the `textConnection()` argument to `read.fwf()` below with your filename.

Note that by setting the `neffects` value for your number of Allele:Effect columns, this will work on as many as you have in your file (in the example, 2).

```
myfile <- 
"Q1        1     1:-0.133302   2: 0.007090
Q2        1     1:-0.050089   2: 0.021212
Q3        1     1: 0.045517   2:-0.038001"

# makes the solution general enough for any number of effects columns
neffects <- 2  # in example, two

# set up column names
cnames <- c("ID", "Chr", as.vector(outer(c("junk", "Effect"), 1:neffects, paste, sep = ".")))

# read the data as a fixed format
mydata <- read.fwf(textConnection(myfile), c(2, 11, rep(c(5, 9), neffects)), 
                   col.names = cnames,
                   colClasses = c("character", "integer", rep(c("character", "numeric"), neffects)),
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
# get rid of unwanted columns
mydata <- mydata[, -grep("^junk", colnames(mydata))]

mydata
##   ID Chr  Effect.1  Effect.2
## 1 Q1   1 -0.133302  0.007090
## 2 Q2   1 -0.050089  0.021212
## 3 Q3   1  0.045517 -0.038001
```